# Spinner, key value and json in kotlin

Tags: json, api, kotlin, spinner, key-value

I'm receving some data from an **API** made with **ACF** and **Wordpress**. I'm parsing the json**,** then I display the result in my android (**kotlin**) application.

But I'm stuck. I need to make a ***key/value*** system for my spinner. I'm using an ArrayList for the moment where I'm adding the index of the loop and the value of the loop.

Then, I'm adding this to a spinner, but I'm only adding a value to this (value is what is showed on my app).

See:

```
    private fun getMulti(array: JSONArray): ArrayList<FormInput>? {
    val arrayInputs: ArrayList<FormInput> = ArrayList()

    if (array.length() > 0) {
        (0 until array.length()).forEach { j ->
            val objInput = array.getJSONObject(j)

            val placeholder2 = objInput.getString(Constants.placeholder)
            val type = objInput.getString(Constants.type)
            val customtag = objInput.getString(Constants.customtag)

            val input = FormInput(null, placeholder2, type, customtag, null)
            if (type == Constants.select) {
                val valuesArray = objInput.getJSONArray(Constants.values)
                Log.i("valeur json : ", valuesArray.toString())
                if (valuesArray.length() > 0) {
                    (0 until valuesArray.length()).forEach {
                        val valeur = input.addItems(valuesArray.getJSONObject(it).getString(Constants.value))
                        if(valuesArray.getJSONObject(it).getString(Constants.prix).toString() != ""){
                            val item = valuesArray.getJSONObject(it).getString(Constants.prix).toString().toFloat()
                            keyValSpinner.add(j, item)
                        }
                    }
                    // On ajoute l'input seulement si il est valide
                    arrayInputs.add(input)
                }
            } else {
                arrayInputs.add(input)
            }
        }
        return arrayInputs
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

This is my json

```
{
  "datas": [
    {
      "id": 472,
      "titre": "Escaliers",
      "order": "4",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "title": "Escaliers",
          "type": "multi",
          "placeholder": "",
          "display_alone": true,
          "values": false,
          "other": false,
          "inputs": [
            {
              "placeholder": "Modèle",
              "type": "select",
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": "Droit",
                  "prix": ""
                },
                {
                  "value": "1/4 tournant 1 volée",
                  "prix": "2362.5"
                },
                {
                  "value": "1/4 tournant 2 volée",
                  "prix": ""
                },
                {
                  "value": "2/4 tournants",
                  "prix": ""
                },
                {
                  "value": "Demi-tour",
                  "prix": ""
                }
              ],
              "customtag": "noTag"
            },
            {
              "placeholder": "Contremarches",
              "type": "select",
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": "Avec contremarche",
                  "prix": "324"
                },
                {
                  "value": "Sans contremarche",
                  "prix": ""
                }
              ],
              "customtag": "noTag"
            },
            {
              "placeholder": "ML garde-corps étage",
              "type": "switch",
              "values": false,
              "customtag": "garde_corps"
            }
          ],
          "custom_tag_alone": "noTagAlone"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My arrayList

```
class KeyValSpinner {
    companion object {
        val keyValSpinner : ArrayList<Any> = ArrayList<Any>()

    }
}
```

For now I have my arrayList with index from 0 to 10 and some prices. But I need to get the value of each object of each spinner, so maybe to an arraylist of arraylist( this one where are stored the value ?)

I've been strugguling for hours with this...

How can I create key/value from this json for each item ?

(PS : I can modify the api as I want)

Comment: Anyone ? I really need help